# What's the official way of passing multiple column names to j in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am pretty sure I solved this before and found a hack or two for this on the web, but I can't get it done properly right now after not using data.table for while. So I wonder: what's the definite solution to pass multiple column names for a use case like this:

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
cols <-  c("mpg","cyl","qsec")

dt[,key := paste('prefix',
             get(cols[1]),
             get(cols[2]),
             get(cols[3]),
             sep = ".")]
```

How can I get the pasting done without explicitly mention all columns. 
Obviously it would be great to simply pass the cols vector to `get`. Yet, that only refers to the first argument while the rest is ignored.
I remember @MattDowle pointed me to not use `eval(as.name())` in an old package of mine which is think that won't be the right solution either...

Answer (score 1):

We can specify it in the `.SDcols` and use `do.call` with `paste` for this case

```
dt[, key := do.call(paste, c('prefix', .SD, sep=".")), .SDcols = cols]
```

---

Or if there is an issue with using `.SDcols`

```
dt[, key := do.call(paste, c('prefix', mget(cols), sep="."))]
```

Comment: thanks. Still, I am not surprised I keep forgetting this :) . Somehow need to remember that `do.call` is applied rowwise here. Do you have any explanation that helps understanding / remember this?

Comment: @MattBannert `paste` is a vectorized function.  You can do the `paste` on a limited number of columns with `paste(col1, col2, col3, sep=".")`, however, if we don't know the column names and also if there are > 10 columns, it becomes a bit too difficult to do this.  With `do.call`, we just need to know the dataset object name or in `data.table`, it is `.SD` (subset of data.table) so that it will do the paste row wise.  `do.call` cannot be used with all the functions for e.g. `sum` (but operator can work '+')